# Oracle - Optimizing looping over all regex matches on CLOB column when only interested in the distinct matches

Tags: regex, oracle, performance, loops, distinct

I'm making a stored procedure that loops over a table (with many thousand rows), and for each row there is a CLOB column from which I want to fetch all matches on a regular expression (sa "FNR"). Thereafter, I want to insert each **distinct** match in a new table. A single CLOB column may contain thousands of matches, but oftentimes it is the same "FNR" that repeats itself in the CLOB - i.e. there are much fewer distinct regex matches, and those are the only ones I'm interested in.
However, the procedure I've made takes ridiculously long time, and I suspect looping over all the matches is the most time consuming part.

My procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MTV_FINN_FNR AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
  v_n NUMBER;
  v_cnt NUMBER;
  v_mtrid NUMBER;
  v_regex_fnr VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
  v_doc CLOB;
  v_fnr VARCHAR2(11);

  BEGIN
    -- Get all rows from table --
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_n FROM TABLE;
    IF v_n > 0 THEN
      -- Loop over all rows --
      FOR i IN 1..v_n LOOP
        SELECT doc, mtrid
          INTO v_doc, v_mtrid
          FROM (SELECT DOC doc, ID mtrid, ROWNUM rnum
            FROM TABLE
            WHERE ROWNUM <=i)
          WHERE rnum >= i;
        IF v_doc IS NOT NULL THEN
          SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(v_doc, v_regex_fnr) INTO v_cnt FROM DUAL;
          IF v_cnt >= 1 THEN
            -- For each regex match - time consuming, right? --
            FOR j IN 1..v_cnt LOOP
              SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm') INTO v_fnr FROM DUAL;
                IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                  INSERT INTO TABLE2(MTR_ID, FNR)
                    SELECT v_mtrid, v_fnr FROM DUAL;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
          END IF;
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
  ROLLBACK;
END;
```

/

Do anybody have an idea of how to optimize this procedure?

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3.0. 
(Btw, I know of the ctx_entity-package, but it is disabled on this version. Still, I'm thinking of enabling it.)

**UPDATE**

After applying the very helpful performance optimizing techniques given by nop77svk, I can with certainty say that the `regexp_substr()` over a `CLOB` is the bottleneck, as there unfortunately were no  performance improvement.
However, I came up with a "hack/workaround" where I minimize the amount of `regexp_substr()` calls, with a tremendous performance improvement. First I thought of making an incrementally "trained" regex, excluding previous matches, but as Oracle doesn't support negative lookahead, this didn't work. I ended up with saving the `CLOB`, and using `regexp_replace()` to remove all occurences of the match. As there were a lot of the same occurences in the CLOB, this saved the procedure from a lot of `regexp_substr()` calls, and it simultaneously dealt with the *distinct* requirement.

Under follows my result, based on nop77svk's contribution. And yes, I'm back to using `DUAL` in the `MERGE`-statement, but is there any way around it here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MTV_FINN_FNR2 AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
v_regex_fnr                 VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
v_fnr                       VARCHAR2(11);

v_doc CLOB;

type rec_table2             is record (
    mtr_id                      table2.mtr_id%type,
    fnr                         table2.fnr%type
);
type arr_table2             is table of rec_table2 index by simple_integer;
table2_bulk                 arr_table2;
table2_row                  rec_table2;
BEGIN
FOR rec IN (
    select doc, MTR_ID as mtrid
    from TABLE
    where DOC is not null
) LOOP
    v_doc := rec.doc;
    loop
        v_fnr := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, 1, 'm');
        exit when v_fnr is null;
        v_vedlegg := REGEXP_REPLACE(v_doc, v_fnr , '' , 1 , 0); -- Incrementally remove all occurences of match from doc --
        IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
            table2_row.mtr_id := rec.mtrid;
            table2_row.fnr := v_fnr;
            table2_bulk(table2_bulk.count+1) := table2_row;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
forall i in indices of table2_bulk
      MERGE INTO TABLE2 T
      USING (SELECT table2_bulk(i).mtr_id mtrid, table2_bulk(i).fnr fnr FROM DUAL) B
      ON (T.MTR_ID = B.mtrid AND T.FNR = B.fnr)
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (T.MTR_ID, T.FNR)
      VALUES (B.mtrid, B.fnr);

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Start with removing the `DUAL` table calls. *Eg:* `v_cnt := REGEXP_COUNT(v_doc, v_regex_fnr)`

Comment: Don't *suspect* the looping is the slow part, check. Though nested loops are usually a bad idea. You're also doing unnecessary conect switching. How may rows are you actually inserting? What is `check_fnr` doing? You could maybe put the values into a collection to eliminate the duplicates and then insert everything in one bulk operation, or use a connect-by loop to extract the matches, etc.; but you need to test where the choke point actually is.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. The amount of rows inserted depends on the amount of regex matches, but it will probably be a couple of thousand in total. Check_fnr is doing a checksum check on the "fnr", as the regex is not enough to identify if the match is actually a national identification number or not. The check_fnr procedure usually takes 0.001-0.003s.

Answer (score 5):

Iteratively tuning your PL/SQL block ...

**Iteration 0:** Fixing syntax errors ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MTV_FINN_FNR AS
  v_n NUMBER;
  v_cnt NUMBER;
  v_mtrid NUMBER;
  v_regex_fnr VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
  v_doc CLOB;
  v_fnr VARCHAR2(11);

  BEGIN
    -- Get all rows from table --
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_n FROM TABLE;
    IF v_n > 0 THEN
      -- Loop over all rows --
      FOR i IN 1..v_n LOOP
        SELECT doc, mtrid
          INTO v_doc, v_mtrid
          FROM (SELECT DOC doc, ID mtrid, ROWNUM rnum
            FROM TABLE
            WHERE ROWNUM <=i)
          WHERE rnum >= i;
        IF v_doc IS NOT NULL THEN
          SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(v_doc, v_regex_fnr) INTO v_cnt FROM DUAL;
          IF v_cnt >= 1 THEN
            -- For each regex match - time consuming, right? --
            FOR j IN 1..v_cnt LOOP
              SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm') INTO v_fnr FROM DUAL;
                IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                  INSERT INTO TABLE2(MTR_ID, FNR)
                    SELECT v_mtrid, v_fnr FROM DUAL;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
          END IF;
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
  ROLLBACK;
END;
```

**Iteration 1:** Removing unnecessary [context switches](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/pfgrf_os.htm#TGDBA95151) and useless row counting ...

```
DECLARE 
    v_cnt NUMBER;
    v_regex_fnr VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
    v_fnr VARCHAR2(11);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        select doc, id as mtrid
        from table
    ) LOOP
        IF rec.doc IS NOT NULL THEN
            v_cnt := REGEXP_COUNT(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr);

            IF v_cnt >= 1 THEN
                -- For each regex match - time consuming, right? --
                FOR j IN 1..v_cnt LOOP
                    v_fnr := REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm');

                    IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                        INSERT INTO TABLE2(MTR_ID, FNR) values (rec.mtrid, v_fnr);
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
        ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

**Iteration 2:** Decreasing number of outer loops ...

```
DECLARE 
    v_cnt NUMBER;
    v_regex_fnr VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
    v_fnr VARCHAR2(11);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        select doc, id as mtrid
        from table
        where doc is not null
    ) LOOP
        v_cnt := REGEXP_COUNT(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr);

        IF v_cnt >= 1 THEN
            -- For each regex match - time consuming, right? --
            FOR j IN 1..v_cnt LOOP
                v_fnr := REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm');

                IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                    INSERT INTO TABLE2(MTR_ID, FNR) values (rec.mtrid, v_fnr);
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
        ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

**Iteration 3:** Shortening the code of iteration 2 ...

```
DECLARE 
    v_regex_fnr VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
    v_fnr VARCHAR2(11);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        select doc, id as mtrid, REGEXP_COUNT(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr) as regexp_cnt
        from table
        where doc is not null
            and regexp_like(doc, v_regex_fnt)
    ) LOOP
        FOR j IN 1..rec.regexp_cnt LOOP
            v_fnr := REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm');

            IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                INSERT INTO TABLE2(MTR_ID, FNR) values (rec.mtrid, v_fnr);
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
        ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

**Iteration 4:** Removing unnecessary `regexp_count()` counting ...

```
DECLARE 
    v_regex_fnr VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
    v_fnr VARCHAR2(11);
    j integer;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        select doc, id as mtrid
        from table
        where doc is not null
    ) LOOP
        j := 1;
        loop
            v_fnr := REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm');
            exit when v_fnt is null;

            IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                INSERT INTO TABLE2(MTR_ID, FNR) values (rec.mtrid, v_fnr);
            END IF;

            j := j + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
        ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

**Iteration 5:** Saving the results to memory and flushing it to DB at once (using the collection binding), plus dealing with the *distinct* requirement ...

```
create or replace type obj_table2
as
object (
    mtr_id                      integer,
    fnr                         varchar2(4000)
);
/
create or replace type arr_table2
as
table of obj_table2;
/

DECLARE 
    v_regex_fnr                 VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
    v_fnr                       VARCHAR2(11);
    j                           integer;

    table2_bulk                 arr_table2 := arr_table2();
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        select doc, id as mtrid
        from table
        where doc is not null
    ) LOOP
        j := 1;
        loop
            v_fnr := REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec.doc, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm');
            exit when v_fnt is null;

            IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                table2_bulk.extend();
                table2_bulk(table2_bulk.last) := new obj_table2(
                    mtr_id => rec.mtrid,
                    fnr => v_fnr
                );
            END IF;

            j := j + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    insert into table2(mtr_id, fnr)
    select mtr_id, fnr
    from table(table2_bulk) X
    minus
    select mtr_id, fnr
    from table2;

    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
        ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

**Iteration 6:** Throwing it all away whilst having decided to [show off detestably](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) ...

```
insert into table2 (mtr_id, fnr)
with xyz (doc, mtrid, fnr, j) as (
    select doc, id as mtrid, cast(null as varchar2(4000)) as fnr, 0 as j
    from table A
    where doc is not null
    --
    union all
    --
    select doc, mtrid,
        regexp_substr(doc, '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))', 1, j+1, 'm') as fnr,
        j+1
    from xyz X
    where j = 0
        or j > 0 and X.fnr is not null
)
select distinct mtrid, fnr
from xyz
where j > 0
    and fnr is not null
    and CHECK_FNR(fnr) = 'TRUE'
;
commit;
```

**Please note** that these code snippets may even not work. Since you did not provide us with any test data setup, we can tune your code only in a hypothetical way.

**Please note** that the slowest part of this is still the `regexp_substr()` over a `CLOB` value. You might want to think about using the `position` parameter of `regexp_substr()` instead of the `occurence` parameter to get the subsequent regexp matches.

Enjoy.

Comment: And for using a recursive CTE; not just me that shows off with those then! It might be helpful to explain what that is doing though, or at least have a doc link

Comment: Thanks, guys. :-) Some links added, also fixed the distinction requirement I forgot about the first time. Alex, for sure you're not the only one :-) , this recursive `with` is a marvel (although buggy occasionally) worth evangelizing.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the really thoroughly explained and good answer! I'll be sure to try these iterations out (and to read the doc to understand what is happening in iteration 6;) )
I should've told what the check_fnr-function was doing, but it has nothing to do with the uniqueness. It is a checksum-check of the "fnr".

Btw, on iteration 5, what would be the best way to do the distinct check? Maybe a check to see if it exists in the table2_bulk before the check_fnr-function is called?

Comment: Yup, just have read it a few minutes ago and modified my answer accordingly. Please don't take these code snippets as the alpha and the omega; rather find inspiration in it - that an iterative approach to performance issues solving can make your life easier. And if my answer makes your code run faster, then I am happy to have helped. :-)

Comment: As for the distinction check in iteration 5 ... Tough nut. You could use schema-level object+collection types and do it via binding a collection (as a datasource, in the `from` clause) to the insert-select instead of using the bulk DML (i.e. the `forall ...`).

Comment: Thanks again, I've learned a lot! Unfortunately, your hints didn't make my code run significantly faster, as the `regexp_substr()` was the only real bottleneck this time. But I found a workaround, by minimizing the `regexp_substr()` calls by incrementally removing the regex matches. Not sure if this is optimal either, but ist certainly helped. See the updated question if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `DUAL` references with static calls. Thus saving the unwanted `context switching` between PL/SQL and SQL Engine.

I also added implicit cursor to process record by record.

Next level of improvement could be [bulk insert](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) into the other table. Though I didn't do it here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MTV_FINN_FNR AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
  v_n NUMBER;
  v_cnt NUMBER;
  v_mtrid NUMBER;
  v_regex_fnr VARCHAR2(54) := '(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2}))(\d{5}))';
  v_doc CLOB;
  v_fnr VARCHAR2(11);

BEGIN
    -- Get all rows from table --
  /* Lets go with a Implicit cursor */
  FOR MYREC IN (SELECT DOC doc, ID mtrid
                  FROM TABLE)
  LOOP
     IF MYREC.DOC IS NOT NULL THEN
        v_cnt := REGEXP_COUNT(MYREC.DOC, v_regex_fnr);
        IF v_cnt >= 1 THEN
        -- For each regex match - time consuming, right? --
            FOR j IN 1..v_cnt LOOP
              v_fnr := REGEXP_SUBSTR(MYREC.DOC, v_regex_fnr, 1, j, 'm');
              IF CHECK_FNR(v_fnr) = 'TRUE' THEN
                INSERT INTO TABLE2(MTR_ID, FNR)
                    VALUES (MYREC.MTRID,v_fnr);
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - rollback');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The error code is ' || SQLCODE || '- ' || SQLERRM);
  ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The context switching wasn't the bottleneck in this case, however, but all the `regexp_substr()` calls were. I've updated the question with a workaround I figured out, if you're interested!